# Where are the iPhoneSimulatorX.X.sdk files in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator

I need the path to what before was something like `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/`, I'm not able to find it...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
iPhoneSimulator.sdk

Legacy simulator runtimes that are downloaded are installed to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes